# jQuery looping a function after a .promise()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, promise

I'm trying to loop a function once a promise is .done(). I seem to be missing something. Any suggestions here?

I want this to run through the function and when the last animation is done, do it again.

I'm including all the JS here, including supporting functions.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.shuffle = function() {
    // credits: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
    var m = this.length, t, i;

    while (m) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

      t = this[m];
      this[m] = this[i];
      this[i] = t;
    }

    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.fn.queueAddClass = function(className) {
        this.queue('fx', function(next) {
            $(this).addClass(className);
            next();
        });
        return this;
    };

    $.fn.animateGrid = function() {
        $('.grid').shuffle().each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(100 * index).queueAddClass('zoom-down');
            $('div', this).delay(100 * index).animate({opacity:0.85}, 100);
        });
        $('.grid').promise().done( function(){
            $('.grid').animate({opacity:0}, 2000);
            $('#mosaic').animateGrid();
        });
    }

    $('#mosaic').animateGrid();

});
```

Comment: xy problem. Simply put, wrong tool for the job. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20loop%20an%20animation%20in%20javascript

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Btw, that `shuffle` function is horrible. Elements in a jQuery collection should always be in DOM tree order.

Comment: @Bergi the issue is that it doesn't loop. I wanted the entire function animateGrid to loop when it is done. Also, I'm not sure what you mean about the DOM tree order. The whole point is to shuffle the order so that they show up randomly.

Comment: I mean that jQuery collections are always ordered in the order the elements appear in the DOM tree. Not sure whether some jQuery methods rely on that invariant. Your `shuffle` function breaks that.

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding animations to the `div`s in the `.grid` not the `.grid` elements themselves, so when you call `.promise` on those it won't have any queue to wait for. So rather use

```
$.fn.animateGrid = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.find('.grid').shuffle().each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(100 * index).queueAddClass('zoom-down');
        $('div', this).delay(100 * index).animate({opacity:0.85}, 100);
    });
    this.find('.grid div').promise().done( function(){
        $('.grid').animate({opacity:0}, 2000);
        self.animateGrid();
    });
}
```

Comment: The .grid elements are getting animations added to them. Why do you need to do the find() when the selector works?

Comment: @DaveMerwin Oh, right, I missed that the grid elements are animated as well. I used `this.find` because otherwise it doesn't make sense to put the function as a jQuery plugin :-)

Comment: Ok. I'm clearly doing something wrong. self.animatedGrid() at the end is not working. My expectation is that once the promise is done and the animate on grid is rung, it should start the function all over again. Is that not right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it should work. Does the promise ever resolve? Do you get output when you put a `console.log()` line in there? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: If I place a console.log () after the self.animateGrid I can see the statement be added to the console and increment up. But the animation function doesn't rerun.

Comment: @DaveMerwin It looks like there is something wrong with your animations themselves - they don't form a cycle. The `.grid` elements always get animated to opacity:0 and get added the zoom-down class, and the `div` elements inside always get animated to opacity:0.85, and it never changes after that so there is no visible animation. What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want the entire function to start over. But now I'm realizing... it can't because I don't have a reset! Is that right?

Comment: @DaveMerwin Yes, exactly. The function *does* start over, it only cannot show any animations any more because the styles haven't been reset.